# Solving a second order differential equation using complex numbers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can i have help solving this second degree differential equation?

$y''+2\lambda y'+ \omega_0^2 y=-N/I$

Where $ y''(\inf)=y'(\inf)=0 $

According to the paper the solution is 
$$ a(t)=2a_0 e^{-\lambda t}(\cos(\omega_n t)+\lambda/\omega_n \sin(\omega_n t))-a_0 $$
where $ \omega_n^2=\omega_0^2-\lambda^2$ and $a_0=N/(I \omega_0^2 )$

The equations is about a Oscillation

where $y''(t)->0$ and $y'(t)->0$ for $t-> infinity$

This solves the partial part of the equation by

$y''+2\lambda y'+ \omega_0^2 y=-N/I$

$0+2\lambda 0+ \omega_0^2 y=-N/I$
$ y=-N/(\omega_0^2I)$

Therefore a partial solution is 
$f(x)_{particial}=-N/(\omega_0^2I)$

Not quite sure if this totally ruins the equation

Comment: Hint: make an *ansatz* $y(t)=e^{Rt}$ for $R \in \mathbb{C}$, and later on use the supersition principle.

Comment: Are you sure about the initial consitions (as they are typed) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
y'' +2\lambda y' + \omega^2_0 y = -N/I
$$
first lets change of variables to tidy up the equation, namely $v = y+\frac{N}{I\omega^2_0}$
$$
v'' + 2\lambda v' +\omega^2_0v = 0
$$

then use the assumption that the solution is of the form 
$$
v = u(t)\mathrm{e}^{rt}
$$
(see comment section above)
then we have
$$
u''\mathrm{e}^{rt} +2ru'\mathrm{e}^{rt} +r^2u\mathrm{e}^{rt} + 2\lambda r u\mathrm{e}^{rt} + 2\lambda u'\mathrm{e}^{rt} + \omega^2_0 u\mathrm{e}^{rt} = 0
$$
thus we get
$$
u'' + 2(r + \lambda)u' + \left(r^2 + 2\lambda r + \omega^2_0\right)u = 0
$$
lets try getting rid of the first derivative by setting $r = -\lambda$ (tip for future try using the parameters to remove terms that may not be ideal)
this results in
$$
u'' + \left(\lambda^2 - 2\lambda^2 + \omega^2_0\right)u = u''  + \left(\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2\right)u  = 0
$$ 
solutions have the form
$$
u(t) = A\sin\left(\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2}t\right) + B\cos\left(\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2}t\right)
$$
therefore we have
$$
y(t) = \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda t}\left[ A\sin\left(\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2}t\right) + B\cos\left(\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2}t\right)\right]-\frac{N}{I\omega^2_0}
$$
usually you define initial conditions instead of the long-term solution at $t\rightarrow \infty$ since you will $\textbf{not}$ satisfy that for any $A,B$. So the trick is that if we write in the form you have in the paper
$$
y(t) = B\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda t}\left[\cos\left(\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2}t\right) + \frac{A}{B}\sin\left(\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2}t\right)\right]-\frac{N}{I\omega^2_0}
$$

$$
B = 2\frac{N}{I\omega^2_0},\\
A = \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2}}\frac{I\omega^2_0}{2N}
$$

$\textbf{Edit:}$
Since we now have $y'(0) = y(0) = 0$ we can compute the constants again
$$
y(0) = B -\frac{N}{I\omega^2_0} = 0
$$
thus
$$
B = \frac{N}{I\omega^2_0}
$$
using
$$
y' = -\lambda \left(y+\frac{N}{I\omega^2_0}\right) +\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda t}\left[ A\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2}\cos\left(\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2}t\right) -B\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2}\sin\left(\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2}t\right)\right]
$$
setting $t=0$
$$
\begin{align}
y'(0) &=& -\lambda \left(y(0)+\frac{N}{I\omega^2_0}\right)+A\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2}\\
&=& -\lambda\frac{N}{I\omega^2_0} +A\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2} = 0
\end{align}
$$
resulting in
$$
A = \frac{\lambda\frac{N}{I\omega^2_0} }{\sqrt{\omega^2_0 - \lambda^2} }
$$

A simple check of your initial equation/solution..applying your initial conditions we find
$$
y(0) = 2a_0 - a_0 = a_0 \neq 0
$$
so i think your original solution is wrong, or the initial conditions are..but you checked them already.

Comment: I can follow the first haft of the answer, but how do you get from equation (4) (labeled from botton) to end result? And is there any mathematical way to define A and B, without just making it "add up" to the paper?

@Chinny84

Comment: I compared the general solution with the case with initial conditions (in the paper). The A and B was the result of the comparison. If I had some time..I could back out the solutions based on a pair of combinations of the following $y''(0), y'(0)$ and $y(0)$. But to be honest Reread that bit of the paper to try and see explicitly the defining ng of the constants..post a link also of the paper.

Comment: I have gone through the paper, and sure enough, its also stated that y'(0) and y(0)=0. And with that in mind i tried to calculate A and B

If you start with y(0)=0 you get 
y(0)=0=B-N/(I*w^2) -> B=N/(I*w^2) which is a 2 short from your calculation? i also tried entering the equationen into a CAS-solver to check, and it also spits out that answer?

Comment: Talked to the lector who wrote the paper, y(0) is not 0, but a_0
With this knowledge i ran throuth the calculations and got the same answer as in the paper 

Thanks a lot for your help, I´m myself started learning about second degree differential equations a few weeks ago, and i must say that your walkthrough and troubbleshooting helped a lot understanding the problem:)

Answer (score 0):

I am a high schooler and I don't know much about it, but shouldn't the solution look like this:

A general equation looks like this:

$$\ddot{x} + a \dot{x} + b x + c = 0$$

Let's substitute $y=x+\frac{c}{b}$ into the differential equation to get rid of $c$ term:

$$\ddot{y} + a \dot{y} + b \left(y - \frac{c}{b}\right) + c = 0$$

$$\ddot{y} + a \dot{y} + b y = 0$$

This is a second-order linear homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients. We can assume a solution of the form $y=Ae^{rt + \phi}$, where $r$ is a constant. Substituting this into the equation, we get:

$$r^2 Ae^{rt + \phi} + r Ae^{rt + \phi} + b Ae^{rt + \phi} = 0$$

$$r^2 + a r + b = 0$$

Thus

$$r_{1,2} = \frac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}$$

The general solution of the differential equation is a linear combination of the two solutions:

$$y(t) = A_1 e^{r_1 t + \phi} + A_2 e^{r_2 t + \phi}$$

where $A_1$, $A_2$ and $\phi$ are constants determined by the initial conditions.

Substituting $y=x+\frac{c}{b}$, we get:

$$x(t) = \left(A_1 e^{r_1 t + \phi} + A_2 e^{r_2 t + \phi}\right) - \frac{c}{b}$$

This is the general solution of the given differential equation.